# path connectedness of space of almost commuting matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices

Let $R$ be a topological ring which is a domain. Let $n$ be an integer and let $\zeta_n$ be a $n$-th root of unity. Denote by $X$ the set of $m$ by $m$ invertible matrices with coefficients in $R$ ($m$ an integer) $\{(A,B)\}$ such that $A^n [A,B]=1$ and $det(A) = \zeta_n$. (Here, $[A,B] = ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$.)

Is there anything known about the path connectedness of this set ? I would be very happy even if an answer is given for the $m=2$ case.